# HTTP Request headers vs form data with method POST

Tags: html, forms, post, file-upload, http-headers

I need to upload a file to server which needs authentication code to be send in request header. So I need to send:

```
POST /upload/file HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Authorization-code: xxxxx

file data
```

I sent a POST request to the server via requestmaker.com with the `Authorization-code` header but without any file data. Server responded OK.

Then I thought to send both `file data` and `Authorization-code` via a HTML form with `method=POST`

I have no in depth knowledge of HTML, so I have no idea what actually is going on behind the scene. I thought, `method=POST` will send the data with request header. But, the server responded something like `Authorization failed`. Then, by `inspecting element` on the webpage, I saw browser didn't send the form values during request. Below is the output of `inspect element->network->header`

```
**General**

Remote Address:x.x.x.x
Request URL:www.example.com
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 OK

**Response Headers**

access-control-allow-credentials:true
access-control-allow-origin:http://mywebsite.com
access-control-expose-headers:Content-Length, Content-Type, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding, Vary, WWW-Authenticate
alternate-protocol:443:quic,p=1
content-length:238
content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:Fri, 24 Apr 2015 22:15:37 GMT
server:UploadServer ("Built on Apr 20 2015 22:37:13 (1429594633)")
status:401
vary:X-Origin
vary:Origin
www-authenticate:realm="https://www.example.com"

**Request Headers**

:authority:www.example.com
:method:POST
:path:/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media
:scheme:https
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
cache-control:max-age=0
content-length:104
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
dnt:1
origin:http://mywebsite.com
referer:http://mywebsite.com/uoh/xxx.html
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
x-client-data:CJC2yQEIo7bJAQiptskBCMS2yQEI8IjKAQieksoB

**Query String Parameters**

uploadType:media

**Form Data**

Authorization-code:xxxx
```

Can anyone please explain this behavior? When actually POST data in forms are sent to server? Any suggestion on how can I send the data in request header?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like 'Authorization-code' should be in the headers section, before the HTTP data section.
Is 'Authorization-code' is a custom header that the server expect to get? (I don't see it in the standard headers - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: Then I don't think you can send it using HTML forms only, you probably need to use some JavaScript code to do that.